# Accessing a Series Based on Partial MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a (very long) pandas Series with a 4-level MultiIndex, something like:

```
objs = ['car', 'bicycle', 'plane']
trials = ['trial A', 'trial B']
moves = [f'mov{i}' for i in range(1,11)]
multi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([objs, trials, moves, range(10)], names=['obj', 'try', 'mov', 'time'])
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(len(multi)))
```

I also have a list of tuples matching **some** of the indices under 'obj' and 'mov'. For example (in reality it's much longer):

```
idxs = [('car','mov1'), ('car','mov6'), ('plane','mov1')]
```

Is there a way to get all rows of `s` where the indices of `multi` contain those in `idxs`? I'm hoping to do this without re-indexing/slicing the Series because as I said it is very long and that would be inefficient.
I read the documentation for [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) & [xs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), neither seem to be what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use list comprehension with pd.DataFrame.query:

```
pd.concat([s.to_frame().query('obj == @i and mov == @j') for i, j in idxs])

OR (as @Jon Nir Suggests which is faster)

pd.concat([s.xs([i,j], level=[obj, mov]) for i,j in idxs])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def eligible(line):
    if (line[0]=='car' and line[2] in ['mov1', 'mov6']) or (line[0]=='plane' and line[2] == 'mov1'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

s[[i for i, line in enumerate(multi) if eligible(line)]]
```

Comment: My actual ```idxs``` list is **much** longer, I can't go over all the conditions there one by one. Also, making those conditions hard-coded into my script is not a very good practice

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε ok, fair enough, I agree.  In it's current state does it have *negative* long-term value though? Does it detract from the community? I would have thought that would be the condition for a downvote.

Comment: @SimonR the downvote is not mine, the comment is, and since your answer came to me in a review queue, I would guess someone reacted to your answer harder than I did.